# How to take a sum (in denominator) for calculating group by weighted average in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science-experience

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
  ['A',1,2,3,4],
  ['A',5,6,7,8],
  ['A',9,10,11,12],
  ['B',13,14,15,16],
  ['B',17,18,19,20],
  ['B',21,22,23,24],
  ['B',25,26,27,28],
  ['C',29,30,31,32],
  ['C',33,34,35,36],
  ['C',37,38,39,40],
  ['D',13,14,15,0],
  ['D',0,18,19,0],
  ['D',0,0,23,0],
  ['D',0,0,0,0],
  ['E',13,14,15,0],
  ['E',0,18,19,0],
  ['F',0,0,23,0],

]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'num4'])
df
```

Then I have the following code to calculate the group by weighted average.

```
weights = [10,20,30,40] 

df=df.groupby('Name').agg(lambda g: sum(g*weights[:len(g)])/sum(weights[:len(g)]))
```

The problem lies in `sum(weights[:len(g)])` because all the groups do not have equal rows. As you can see above, `group A has 3 rows, B has 4 rows, C has 3 rows, D has 4 rows, E has 2 rows and F has 1 row`.
Depending upon the rows, it needs to calculate the sum.
Now, the above code returns me the weighted average by calculating

**For Group A, the first column calculates the weighted average as (1 X 10+5 X 20+9 X 30)/60 but it should calculate the weighted average as (1 X20+5 X 30+9 X 40)/90**

**For Group E, the first column calculates the weighted average as (13 X 10+0 X 20)/30 but it should calculate the weighted average as (13 X 30+0 X 40)/70**

**Current Result**

[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i edit your code little bit

```
n = len(weights)
df=df.groupby('Name').agg(lambda g: sum(g*weights[n-len(g):])/sum(weights[n-len(g):]))
```

output(`df`):

```
    num1    num2    num3    num4
Name                
A   5.9     6.9     7.9     8.9
B   21.0    22.0    23.0    24.0
C   33.9    34.9    35.9    36.9
D   1.3     5.0     12.2    0.0
E   5.6     16.3    17.3    0.0
F   0.0     0.0     23.0    0.0
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working as per my expectation. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

@PandaKim's solution suffices; for efficiency, depending on your data size, you may have to take a longer route:

```py
n = len(weights)
pos = n - df.groupby('Name').size()
pos = [weights[posn : n] for posn in pos]
pos = np.concatenate(pos)
(df
.set_index('Name')
.mul(pos, axis=0)
.assign(wt = pos)
.groupby('Name')
.sum()
.pipe(lambda df: df.filter(like='num')
                   .div(df.wt, axis=0)
     )
)

           num1       num2       num3       num4
Name
A      5.888889   6.888889   7.888889   8.888889
B     21.000000  22.000000  23.000000  24.000000
C     33.888889  34.888889  35.888889  36.888889
D      1.300000   5.000000  12.200000   0.000000
E      5.571429  16.285714  17.285714   0.000000
F      0.000000   0.000000  23.000000   0.000000
```